# Replace tags in a word file

Tags: java, docx4j

I've some tags in a word file which looks like `<tag>`.
Now I get the content of the Word file with docx4j and loop through every line and search for this tag. When I find one, then i replace it with a String. But this code i tried doesn't work and now i really don't know how i can realise it!

Here's the code i've already tried:

```
WordprocessingMLPackage wpml = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(new File(path));

MainDocumentPart mdp = wpml.getMainDocumentPart();

List<Object> content = mdp.getContent();
String line;
for (Object object : content) {
    line = object.toString();
    if (line.contains("<tag>")) {
        line.replace("<tag>", "<newTag>");
    }
}
```

Any tips or solutions how i can achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of your problems is that you modify `String line` which has no effect on anything. `line.replace("<tag>", "<newTag>");` result of this operation is ignored. you would definitely want to do sth with that, right?

Also, if `object` in your loop is not an instaneOf `String`, then `line` and `object` are pointing to different objects.

You need to modify contents but not the way you're doing this. Please read [getting started](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/docs/Docx4j_GettingStarted.html)

Also there are lots of examples (sample code) in source code [download section](http://www.docx4java.org/downloads.html)

If you have any concrete problems after reading the getting started, we'll be happy to help you.

Comment: So I must manipulate the object directly? And how can I do that? Or should I write the line back in the object?

Comment: yes, you need to manipulate contents, but not the way you're doing this. Refer here  for example: http://www.docx4java.org/blog/2013/05/docx4jpptxxlsx-online-code-generation/

Answer (score 1):

The things in your List will be org.docx4j.wml.P (paragraphs), or Tbl (tables) or other block level content.

Paragraphs contain runs, which in turn contain the actual text.

For the suggested way of doing what you want to do, see the VariableReplace sample.

Better yet, consider content control data binding.

Otherwise, if you want to roll your own approach, see the Getting Started guide for how to traverse, or use JAXB-level XPath.

Answer (score 0):

First you should use `replaceAll()` instead of `replace()`.

Then you should store this String into an object you can serialize back after modification to the Word file.

Furthermore I think that it would also be good to handle closing tags (if there some) ...

Comment: So I should create a new object and append every String to this object...? And thanks for the tip with `replaceAll`

Comment: I'm not familiar with the word processing package but I guess there is a way to serialize/marshall some content. If yes, then construct a new object which you can hand over and write the data in it. After that store it with the marshalling method.

Answer (score 0):

String (line) is immutable, therefore `replace("<tag>", "<newTag>")` does not modify your `line` it creates a new modified one.

Your code shoudl do something like this:

```
for (Object object : content) {
    line = object.toString();
    if (line.contains("<tag>")) {
       line= line.replaceAll("<tag>", "<newTag>");
    }
    writeLineToNewFile(line);
}
```

or shorter:

```
for (Object object : content) {
      writeLineToNewFile(object.toString().replace("<tag>", "<newTag>");
}
```

Comment: Have a loolk at `FileWriter` or `FileOutputStream` depending if you want to write `String`s or raw bytes.